# The process cannot access file 'C:/.......' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, file, tiff

In my application that I wrote in C#, I have the files merged and one of the files I merged is deleted. When I try to merge merged files Process cannot access file '5-1325106-2020004.tif' because it is being used by another process. I get an error

```
  GdPictureUtil.MergeFiles(sourceFiles, targetFileName);

                foreach (var item in sourceFiles)
                {
                   
                    if (item != targetFileName)
                    {
                        File.Delete(item); //  it goes wrong here
                    }
                    
                    
                }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The error message possibly means what it says; another process has the file open

Comment: When working with any IO its important to implement, and use IDisposable. When you access resources in a using block, file locks generally go away.

Comment: As @AnthonyG. pointed out, it is possible that your MergeFiles function hasn't freed the files that were merged. Make sure to use `using` (you may not have to use `IDisposable`, depending on how MergeFiles operates.